# MYSQL - How to sort column with ORDER BY and LIMIT and then sort those results by another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I am currently using a MYSQL query that uses a formula to determine the similarity of rows and then order them by their difference. The query works perfect, but now I am trying to introduce LIMIT and I am have trouble. My original query is below.

```
SELECT t2.*, ABS(t1.v1-t2.v1)+ABS(t1.v2-t2.v2)+ABS(t1.v3-t2.v3) AS diff
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id=1) AS t1
JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t1.id <> t2.id
ORDER BY diff;
```

Now I introduced a LIMIT expression and two ORDER BY statements and it isn't working correctly. My ultimate goal is to join the tables like above, then sort the table by the id row, limit the results to 10, and then resort the table by diff ASC. Everything works fine up until the final ORDER BY of the diff, it is sorting the id column and then showing the first 10 results but not reordering the results by diff. I have been trying:

```
SELECT t2.*, ABS(t1.v1-t2.v1)+ABS(t1.v2-t2.v2)+ABS(t1.v3-t2.v3) AS diff
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id=1) AS t1
JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t1.id <> t2.id
ORDER BY id, diff LIMIT 10;
```

Like I said previously, the query above just keeps the rows sorted by id and limits the results to 10, but does not execute the final ORDER BY DIFF.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Just wrap the whole select in another select statement: `select * from <current select statement> order by diff`.

Comment: @Andrew, please post that as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t2.*, ABS(t1.v1-t2.v1)+ABS(t1.v2-t2.v2)+ABS(t1.v3-t2.v3) AS diff
      FROM tbl t1 JOIN
           tbl t2
           ON t1.id <> t2.id and t1.id = 1
      ORDER BY t2.id
      LIMIT 10
     ) t
ORDER BY diff;
```

You have `position` in your queries.  I don't know what that is.  Also, the subquery for `t1` is unnecessary.  You can just include the `id` in the `on` clause.

Comment: That's it! Thank you Gordon!!